# how to retrieve json file data in elastic search using sense plugin

Tags: json, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-jdbc-river, sense

I am new to elastic search. I am using sense plugin. While i am trying to retrieve data from JSON file using command

```
POST/bank/accounts/_bulk?pretty @accounts.json
```

and the output in sense console is giving like:

> Request failed to get to the server (status code: 0):

I want to know which command should I type in Sense to retrieve data from JSON file.

Comment: Can you give more information about the contents of you accounts.json file?

Comment: yeah it contains name,account number,address,balance,age,gender and email id and here i am giving you the link http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_exploring_your_data.html. thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the output.I have just copied the total content in the json file and paste it in sense editor n got the output
Thank you

Comment: What do you mean by pasting in sense?

Comment: open the json file in notepad and copy the whole json file and paste in the sense plugin editor.

Comment: Ok understood. But my JSON file contains a million lines. Can't open it in notepad!

Comment: have you tried with curl---     curl -XPOST 'http://jfblouvmlxecs01:9200/test/test/1' -d @lane.json

Answer (score 0):

no need to paste the content to sense editor.
just get postman from https://www.getpostman.com/docs/environments give it the file location with `/bank/accounts/_bulk?pretty` command.
[image]